# flutterMap remove the white stripes at the top and bottom

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

when using the flutter_map library, white stripes are displayed when scrolling the map up or down
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGyhJ.png)

How to make the map height equal to the screen height
when changing the max zoom and scrolling the problem remains

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in `flutter_map`'s [example](https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map/blob/0fef8d6d36a735132b1b6cbe4624265beb4740bf/example/lib/pages/home.dart#L39C15-L44C17.). Just add such `cameraConstraint` to `MapOptions`:

```dart
return FlutterMap(
  options: MapOptions(
    cameraConstraint: flutter_map.CameraConstraint.contain(
      bounds: flutter_map.LatLngBounds(
        const LatLng(-90, -180),
        const LatLng(90, 180),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)`
```